# Can I dynamically populate a ListView in an ActionBarActivity?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I saw a number of examples that populated ListViews in a ListActivity.  I want both a dynamically populated ListView, but in an activity with an action bar.

So instead of (as in the examples I've seen):

```
public class EditHolidaysActivity extends ListActivity {
```

I have:

```
public class EditHolidaysActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

But the setListAdapter method cannot be resolved.  What method might I use to populate the ListView?  Here are snippets of the xml and java:

```
    ...
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Anni"
        android:id="@+id/chkbxAnniversary"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="saveAnniPref"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
public class EditHolidaysActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = MainActivity.PREFS_NAME;
    private final static String TEXT_DATA_KEY = "textData";
    private CommentsDataSource datasource;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_holidays);

        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

        // use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not create an instance of `ListView myListView` use `myListView = (ListView)findByViewId(R.id.lstName)`, then call `myListView.setAdapter(adapter)`?

Comment: Correction; use `myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstName)` - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class EditHolidaysActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = MainActivity.PREFS_NAME;
private final static String TEXT_DATA_KEY = "textData";
private CommentsDataSource datasource;
private ListView lstView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_holidays);

    lstView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

    // use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
    // elements in a ListView
    ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```